# Python OOP if statement

Tags: python

new to python and I'm stuck in the last step in this exercise 
how can I add in **print_pixel_info(self):** to check if 2 out of the 3 color values are equal to 0 then print the third value which is not 0?

the program prints right now:

X: 5,Y: 6, Color: (250,0,0)

X: 5,Y: 6, Color: (83,83,83)

The goal is to print:

(in this case, red is 250 green and blue is 0 so it prints 'red', if the values were (0,250,0) it should print 'green' instead)

X: 5, Y: 6, Color: (250, 0, 0) Red

X: 5, Y: 6, Color: (83, 83, 83)**

```
class Pixel:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y= 0, red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0): 
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._red = red
        self._green = green
        self._blue = blue

    def set_coords(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def set_grayscale(self):
        average = (self._red + self._blue + self._green)/3
        self._red = int(average)
        self._blue = int(average)
        self._green = int(average)

    **def print_pixel_info(self):
        print("X: {},Y: {}, Color: ({},{},{}) {}".format(self._x,self._y,self._red,self._green,self._blue))**


def main():
    p = Pixel(5, 6, 250)
    p.print_pixel_info()
    p.set_grayscale()
    p.print_pixel_info()

main()
```

Thank you, hopefully my question is explained in a way which other people can understand it lol

Comment: You can store the rgb as array then use the python function set

Comment: The print statement has 6 {} but you are giving 5 arguments to format

Comment: What it should print when 2 values are not 0 ?

Comment: Also to print the text "RED" you should have an if statement to check when the values of blue and green are zero and print("RED") here you are not passing "RED" to format

Comment: Thank you everyone was really helpful and fast for first question asked in here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `print_pixel_info()` something like this:

```py
def print_pixel_info(self):
        color = ""
        if self._red == 0 and self._green == 0:
            color = "Blue"
        elif self._green == 0 and self._blue == 0:
            color = "Red"
        elif self._red == 0 and self._blue == 0:
            color = "Green"

        print("X: {},Y: {}, Color: ({},{},{}) {}".format(self._x,self._y,self._red,self._green,self._blue, color))
```

As you haven't mentioned what should be displayed when 2 colors are not zero. You can add a default value for `color` in the above code.

Comment: There is no need for the " color if color else "" " part color will not change from "" if none of the conditions are met